# Ways to authenticate mobile phone number

Tags: mobile, mobile-application, phone-numbers

I am making a mobile application for Android and IOS with accounts that are linked to mobile phone numbers. I have looked into SMS authentication but it is relatively expensive for the type of app I am making. I have a textbox that asks for a phone number and I need a way to verify that the entered number is the correct phone number. Is there any alternative ways to verify a mobile phone number?

Comment: I'm not sure this is a UX question. You've already decided on the User Experience - they verify via mobile. It sounds more like you're looking for a technical solution to it.

Comment: @JonW Isn't the way the user must authenticate their phone number part of the user experience? The user experience will be affected by how the phone number is verified.

Answer (score 2):

- let people login via facebook or other social platforms that already have verified phone numbers
- let users text a unique code, or give a missed call to particular phone number
- notifications might help, if you want to verify device

Answer (score 0):

> Is there any alternative ways to verify a mobile phone number?

There are ways to verify that a phone number is valid, but in your case you also want to verify that the phone number belongs to the user. There's no way to verify that without sending some sort of confirmation code via text or call, and having your user confirm that code in your application.

Comment: Yeah. Want to confirm the number? Call it.